# Objective-C UIScrollView with Paging, Video in background thread stops when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am having a problem with my app regarding this topic's title.
On my entry screen I am playing a video in background, over the video I have positioned a Scrollview with Paging. The video plays nice but when I sliding over ScrollView to change page, the video stops for a seconds and then plays normally again.
I am pretty sure this is a main UI thread thing but don't know how to handle it. I tried with performSelectorInBackground and other methods, but none of them work.

For the ScrollView I only use this code

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

Hope someone can help.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you use any NSTimer?

Comment: Well scroll and timers wont work together. Videos have frames and quality of any video is depends on `frames per second`. Video player use timers to play video , here is the issue.

Comment: How do you playing the video? With help of what classes?